# Поведение конструкторов при наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп

Объясните мне, пожалуйста, поведение конструкторов при наследовании. Я прекрасно понимаю, что сли у нас есть класс B, который наследуется от А, то при объявлении объекта класса B вызывается сначала конструктор А, затем конструктор В. Но вот вопрос. Если у нас есть конструктор в классе А, а в классе B его нет, то каким образом происходит вызов конструктора при объявлении объекта класса B? Два раза вызывается конструктор А?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    int X;
    int Y;
    A() {
        X = rand() % 100;
        Y = rand() % 200 + 100;
    }
public:
    virtual void Date() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void Date() {
        cout << "X = " << X << "\n";
        cout << "Y = " << Y << "\n";
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual void Date() {
        cout << "X = " << X << "\t" << "Y = " << Y << "\n";
    }
};

void date(B *object) {
    object->Date();
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    B b;
    C c;
    date(&b);
    date(&c);
}
```

В этой программе я реализую полиморфизм посредством переопределения метода Date, который вывод инфу о полях либо в строчку, либо один под другим.

Comment: А ну-ка покажите пример кода. Нельзя создать объект, у которого нет конструктора (с редкими исключениями). Я скорее поверю, что у В есть конструктор, но он был неявно сгенерирован компилятором.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ваших классов `B` и `C` есть конструкторы, неявно сгенерированные компилятором. Они ведут себя (почти) как `B() {}`, или как `B() : A() {}`, который делает то же самое (аналогично для `C`).

То есть все как обычно - вызываются конструкторы `A` и `B`, и, соответственно, `A` и `C`. Но конструкторы `B` и `C` ничего не делают.

> при объявлении объекта класса B вызывается сначала конструктор А, затем конструктор В

Если придираться, это не совсем верно. Сначала вызывается конструктор `B`. Первым делом он инициализирует члены класса и его родителей, то есть вызывает конструктор `A`, а уже потом выполняет свое тело.

То есть, хотя *тело* конструктора `A` выполняется до `B`, сам конструктор `A` вызывается не до конструктора `B`, а *из* него, до захода в его тело.

Comment: благодарю за пояснение, теперь все вроде стало на свои места

Comment: @Аксолотль Всегда пожалуйста! Можно нажать галочку слева, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.